# Error Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join, pdo

Please help, 
i got error "Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in ... on line...".

Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT `id`, `kategori`, `sub_kategori` FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC"; 

$stmt = $DB_con->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute();   

$kategori = array();

if($stmt->rowCount()>0) {                       
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $kategori = print($row['kategori']);    
}
}else{
 echo "Nothing here...";                
}

join($kategori, ',');
```

I expect the output  : Data,Data,Data,Data,Book,Book
but the actual output is "DataDataDataDataBookBook" anda error "Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in ... on line..."

Comment: i'm sorry, im still learning. please guide me

Answer (score 3):

Just append `$row['kategori']` in each iteration and change the order of parameteres in `join()` or `implode()` call:

```
<?php

// Get data
$query = "SELECT `id`, `kategori`, `sub_kategori` FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC"; 
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();   

// Fetch data    
$kategori = array();
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {                       
   while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       $kategori[] = $row['kategori'];    
   }
} else {
    echo "Nothing here...";                
}

// Output
echo implode(',', $kategori);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, the error is gone but the result show is still "DataDataDataDataBookBook", without any ","

Comment: @thenoirlatte Please, check updated answer, I've edited some errors.

Comment: @thenoirlatte You are welcome. If you think that this or any other answer is the best solution to your problem, you may accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to fetching a bunch of records and then joining them together would be to use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in mysql to do the work for you.  Also as you are not binding anything - you can just call `query()`.  Then you will have 1 row from the database with the content - so the last bit is to say if it's empty, then set the value to `Nothing here...` (done using `?:`)
...

```
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`kategori`) as kategori 
             FROM `table` 
             ORDER BY `id` DESC"; 

$stmt = $DB_con->query($query);
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$output = $row['kategori']?:"Nothing here...";
echo $output;
```

If you still need the individual data rows, then another alternative is to use `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` and `fetchAll()` to return the results, then `implode()` as in the other solution...

```
$query = "SELECT `kategori` 
             FROM `table` 
             ORDER BY `id` DESC"; 

$stmt = $DB_con->query($query);
$kategori=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
echo implode(',', $kategori)?:"Nothing here...";
```

Comment: Thank you.......yes i agree, but actually i try to combine the result with some html, so...i dont know

Comment: Added an alternative which also gives an array of the values.